# How to assure an image has been served right in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

(If some editor helps me to title this question better, I'll be more than thankful)

I have a controller which has a method that serves a PNG image in a Storage, basically it says:

```
public function background($id) {
    $campaign = Campaign::find($id);
    $file = Storage::get($campaign->background);
    return new Response($file, 200);
}
```

In the routes I have:

```
Route::get('/campaign/background/{id}', 
    'CampaignController@background')->name('campaign.background');
```

So, if I call the route inside an `<img ...>` HTML tag, it works perfectly:

```
<img src="{{ route('campaign.background', [id => 1]) }}" class="...">
```

It will give me the background image for the class Campaign with the id 1

Now, my problem is when I try to load several imgs, like in a Bootstrap 4 carousel, I have:

```
<div id="caro" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ route('campaign.background', ['id' => '4']) }}?auto=yes" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ route('campaign.background', ['id' => '14']) }}?auto=yes" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ route('campaign.background', ['id' => '2']) }}?auto=yes" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Only the first image (id 4) is shown correctly, id's 14 and 2 sometimes loads correctly, but most times, they don't, they only show the ALT.

I think it must be something related to the cache, if I reload the page several times, all the imgs appear.

I'm using Laravel 5.7, PHP 7.2.10, Apache 2.4.35 over Windows 10

Comment: Does the dev tool in your browser (Console or Network) give you any more information? Is it a 404 error or something else?

Comment: No, it's not. If I load the id's 14 and 2 separately it works okay, even if I change the order to display say 14, 2 and 4 in this example, 14 will show while 2 and 4, in most cases won't. If I reload (ctrl-R) the page several times, the three images will show correctly. I got no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some headers are missing and the browser doesn't know what kind of file you're serving?

You could try this:

```
public function background($id) {
    $campaign = Campaign::find($id);
    return Storage::response($campaign->background);
}
```

`Storage::response()` should automatically set Content-Type, Content-Disposition, size, and maybe a few others I'm forgetting about. These headers will help browsers determine what kind of content was in the response.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know. What puzzles me is that sometimes it works, but most of the time it doesn't.

Comment: Worked perfectly, so yeah, must be something about the headers as you said